# When can we define the "operation preserving"-propriety of a map $F$ as: $(a*b) = F(a)*F(b)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

[I have read that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism#Definition), given two input elements $(a,b)$, and given a binary operation $*$, a map $F$ is said to be operation-preserving if $F(a*b) = F(a)*F(b)$. [For example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle), linear maps always preserve the operation of vector addition (as well as vector multiplication):
$F(a+b) = F(a)+F(b)$.
(I'm aware that in general there should be *two* operations $($#$,*)$ such that $F(a$#$b) = F(a)*(b)$, here just for simplicity I'm considering the case in which # = $*$, as in the vector addition example).

At the same time i have read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120916/map-preserving-indefinite-scalar-product-must-be-linear) that:

> If a map $T:V \to V$ preserves $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$, then $\langle Tv,Tw \rangle = \langle v,w \rangle$ for all $v,w \in V$.

So when the operation $*$ is the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$, the "operation preserving"-propriety of a map $F$ can be written as $(a*b) = F(a)*F(b)$, and not anymore as $F(a*b) = F(a)*F(b)$ as stated in the beginning. If it could be written as $F(a*b) = F(a)*F(b)$, then we would have: $\langle Tv,Tw \rangle = T\langle v,w \rangle$.

So my question is: in general, when can we write the operation-preserving propriety of a map as $(a*b) = F(a)*F(b)$ (e.g: operation of inner product) and when can we write it as $F(a*b) = F(a)*F(b)$ (e.g.: operation of vector addition)?

Please note that i'm interested in a general answer, not specific to the inner product / vector addition examples.

Comment: What makes the difference (and lets you guess the answer to your question) is that the inner product does not take its values in $T$'s codomain $V.$

Comment: how can we generalise this fact in order to get a *universally-valid* mathematical definition/expression of *operation-preserving propriety*?

Comment: @TrentKent6 the word you are searching for is *morphism*, the basic and essential notion of category theory

Comment: @Masacroso so what conditions allow a morphism to be written as  $F(a*b) = F(a)*F(b)$ and what conditions allow it to be written as $(a*b) = F(a)*F(b)$?

Comment: As @AnneBauval indicated, $F$ and $*$ have to take their values in the same set/structure for the first form to be available. I'm afraid it's nothing very deep - just checking that domains and co-domains match up for all the maps you want to apply.